# Turn off system versioning of temporal table that is used in indexed views

Tags: sql-server, indexed-views

I have a table that is used by a number of indexed views that I want to convert to a temporal table. All the commands to add the necessary columns and to set SYSTEM_VERSIONING=ON with a history table all succeeded. But now I can not disable system versioning with this command

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
```

I get the error
`Cannot ALTER 'MyTable' because it is being referenced by object 'MyIndexedViewThatReferencesMyTable'.`

It seems impractical to delete all views, alter MyTable, then recreate all views in order to accomplish this. Is there another way to get this table back to non-temporal?

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-create the views, just alter, removing schemabinding (which will drop the indexes), make your change to the underlying table, then alter again (putting schemabinding back), and re-create the indexes. It's still a lot of work, sure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand our queries on indexed views use a lot of `with (noexpand)` hints because of legacy code from SQL standard version days. Any ideas of how to avoid application errors while indexed views are set to normal views?

Comment: Nothing clever comes to mind, aside from doing everything during a maintenance window (maybe set the database to single_user so the application gets connection errors instead of logical errors). You could migrate the data to a new table, create new indexed views (and interim views with instead of triggers to keep this transparent for DML operations), then drop the old objects and rename the new ones. This isn't any less complex than deleting all the views and re-creating them, it just allows you to prioritize preventing application errors (at the cost of a little more work).

Comment: (Also, I feel like NOEXPAND should be a no-op when a view isn't indexed, [and so do a few others](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/293508/some-query-hints-errors-should-have-a-warning-only-option). Unfortunately, Microsoft didn't agree.)